# how to get child attribute value like id on click in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

When I click on an `li` it should get the current clicked `li` id instead of the parent `li` id. Suppose I have code like below, when I click on the child `li` it is giving me both the parent id and current `li` id. I want only the current `li` id.

Please help me to correct this. Thanks in advance.

```js
$('.scrollTo').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var arr = id.split('-');
  var menu_id = arr[2];
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#" + menu_id).offset().top
  }, 500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="15" class="scrollTo">
    <ul>
      <li id="12" class="scrollTo"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent event bubbling to DOM tree by using [`stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) method.

```js
$('.scrollTo').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="15" class="scrollTo">
    <ul>
      <li id="12" class="scrollTo"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Fixed the typo for you :)

Comment: That's because your `split()` and `animate()` logic doesn't work given the small example you posted. The part which retrieves the `id` works fine, though: https://jsfiddle.net/bvp80ouz/

Comment: @Dev5 :  `arr[2]` would be undefined

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.scrollTo').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log("id", id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="15" class="scrollTo">
    <ul>
      <li id="12" class="scrollTo"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```